# Best practice to run Tensorflow app on GCP?

Tags: tensorflow, google-cloud-platform, google-cloud-dataproc, google-cloud-ai

I wish to run a Python app that uses Tensorflow to run simulations and outputs results to a csv file.

I want to run it on GCP. My plan was to run it in a Dataproc cluster using [Tony](https://cloud.google.com/blog/products/ai-machine-learning/ai-in-depth-cloud-dataproc-meets-tensorflow-on-yarn-let-tony-help-you-train-right-in-your-cluster).

It seems there are many GCP ways of doing ML stuff such as using [AI Platform](https://cloud.google.com/ai-platform/), and I wondered if there are easier/better ways of achieving my aim.

Comment: +1 on Igor answer, normally I would start with AI Platform Notebooks for experimentation and then move to AI Platform Training and Prediction for production. In both we support latest stable versions of TensorFlow 1.15 and 2.1. Also you can use any TF version if needed

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I would suggest to use [Google Cloud AI platform](https://cloud.google.com/ai-platform/) to achieve your goal, because if you do not have dependency on Hadoop ecosystem there no need to use Tony on Dataproc and it should be much easier to use Google Cloud AI platform for your use case.