# How do I add machines to GCP AI Platform?

Tags: python, apache-spark, google-cloud-platform, google-cloud-dataproc, gcp-ai-platform-notebook

From [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/60935881/best-practice-to-run-tensorflow-app-on-gcp?noredirect=1#comment107820772_60935881) question's advice, I have been running a Python app that uses Tensorflow to run simulations and outputs results to a csv file, using AI Platform. I have been using Jupyter  following [this](https://medium.com/google-cloud/using-google-cloud-ai-platform-notebooks-as-a-web-based-python-ide-e729e0dc6eed).

Works great, and I have increased my VM's size to run it faster.

Now how do I add machines to make it run even faster, maybe using Spark and/or Dataproc or, ideally, something simpler?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

AI Platform notebooks are based on a single machine. To use a cluster of computers to process the data you can use a Jupyter notebook on Dataproc. To have this auto-configured, use a cluster similar to:

```sh
REGION=<gce_region>
gcloud beta dataproc clusters create ${CLUSTER_NAME} \ 
  --region ${REGION} \
  --optional-components ANACONDA,JUPYTER \
  --initialization-actions gs://goog-dataproc-initialization-actions-${REGION}/tony/tony.sh \
  --enable-component-gateway
```

This will provide a Spark cluster that has a Jupyter notebook configured and a framework for running Tensorflow on a cluster (Tony).

For more on Dataproc notebooks check out: 
https://medium.com/google-cloud/apache-spark-and-jupyter-notebooks-made-easy-with-dataproc-component-gateway-fa91d48d6a5a

And for more on Tony, check out [this post](https://cloud.google.com/blog/products/ai-machine-learning/ai-in-depth-cloud-dataproc-meets-tensorflow-on-yarn-let-tony-help-you-train-right-in-your-cluster).

If your looking for more of a serverless approach, you could also check out AI Platform distributed training:

- https://cloud.google.com/ai-platform/training/docs/packaging-trainer
- https://cloud.google.com/ai-platform/training/docs/distributed-training-containers

Comment: Many thanks, very helpful. Sure wish there was some kind of summary of use cases for the many different products on GCP.